# Where clause with like to look out for 4 digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2012.

I need to look for every string that has the following format: `txxxxjsd`
where `xxxx` is always an algarism. The first CHARACTER can be any LETTER (never a number) and it is always only ONE, *`jsd`* can be any letter but ***never*** a number.
So the sequence of the string is:  one letter, one algarism, one algarism, one algarism, one algarism, any letter and after the 6th character it can be a number (see examples below).

I've tried with

```
select name
from table a
where name like  like '[a-z] + '[0-9]{4}' + '%'
```

also with

```
select name
    from table a
    where name like  like '[a-z]' + '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' + '%'
```

It is not working for the part after the 4th algarism.

Examples:

```
s4567tty ---->   this should appear in the result
s45677ty ---->   this should NOT appear
r4546t656 --->   this should appear in the result
45656ty  ---->   this should NOT appear
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
where name like '[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]%'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31244273042fdef7291d1841eef66384) is a DB<>Fiddle.

Comment: see the third example, please. I added in the parenthesis that this case should be taken into account

Comment: @graphene . . . That is what this does.

Comment: @graphene . . . That would require a number after the first six characters.

Comment: In most configuations SQLServer is not case sensitive, so this could possibly be simplified by removing the `a-z`